# If $E(X^2)$ exists, $E(X)$ exists

Tags: probability

How do I prove this? Is it even true?

I proved the obvious cases, but don't know how to prove/disprove the $0\lt x\lt 1$ case.

IF $E(X^2)$ exists, $\sum_{x\in\omega}x^2P(x)\lt \infty$. Therefore:

$$\forall x \le 0:\space \sum_{x\in\omega}xP(x) \le \sum_{x\in\omega}x^2P(x) = E(X^2)\lt \infty \\ 
\forall x\ge 1:\space \sum_{x\in\omega}xP(x) \le \sum_{x\in\omega}x^2P(x) = E(X^2)\lt \infty$$

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) is the fastest way to show this.
$$E(X)^2 \leq E(X^2)$$

Comment: Will this be valid then?


$E(X) \gt \infty$ if and only if $E(X)^2 \gt \infty$, but $E(X)^2 \le E(X^2)$, therefore $E(X) \gt \infty$ if and only if $E(X^2) \gt \infty$

Comment: This is not very convincing to me, it assumes that either $E(X)$ exists or it's infinite, but that's not always the case (eg, take the Cauchy distribution)

Comment: @yuvalz Yes it is valid for integrable or positive random variables , in the latter case if $E(X) = \infty$ then $E(X^2) = \infty$

Comment: @Bunder The issue is that for Cauchy random variables, if we say that $E[X^2]$ exists (having value $\infty$ as you say) then, since $E[X]$ is _undefined_ and _does not exist, it cannot be said that "If $E[X^2]$ exists, then $E[X]$ also exists."

Comment: @DilipSarwate I'll rephrase the question: Is it $E(|X|)$ finite if $E(X^2)$ is finite?. The answer is yes. If $E(|X|) = \infty$ (i.e $E(X)$ undefined) does not matter to the question.

Comment: @Bunder The question clearly asks whether $E[X]$ _exists_ whenever $E[X^2]$ exists. If $E[X^2]$ is finite, then it exists and as I showed in my answer, this implies that $E[|X|]$ also exists and is finite, and so does $E[X]$. If the integral for $E[X^2]$ diverges but we still agree to say that $E[X^2]$ _exists_, then $E[|X|]$ might exist in the same sense of being the value of a divergent integral, but $E[X]$ might be undefined, that is, not exist even in the sense of being the value of a divergent integral. Leonbloy's comment on your proof making assumptions about $E[X]$ is on target.

Answer (score 7):

I will assume that "exists" means that the expectation in question is finite.

Then,
since $|x|< 1+x^2$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$, $E[|X|] < 1+E[X^2] < \infty$, and so $E[X]$ also exists.

Answer (score 3):

$E(X)$ exists iff $\int|x|  f_X(x) \, dx < \infty$. But

$$\int_{|x|\le1}  |x|f_X(x) \, dx + \int_{|x|>1} |x| f_X(x) \, dx \le\\\le
\int_{|x|\le1}  f_X(x) \, dx + \int_{|x|>1} x^2 f_X(x) \, dx \le \\ 
\le 1 + E(X^2) \le \infty
$$

Comment: Is it given that $X$ admits a density?

Comment: @StefanHansen: not really. one could make this more rigourous, by using distribution, but it's not worth the pain, the elegant way is already given by Dilip's answer(+1).